# jQuery Select2 ajax data source not triggered / called

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to bind my Select2 dropdown list to an MVC (v5.2.3) controller of my application.

I've pretty much copied the code from the [demo](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax):

```
<select id="select-ticket-test" class="duplicate-post-select" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Select ticket">
    <option></option>
    <option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
</select>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function formatTicket(ticket) {
            if (ticket.loading) {
                return ticket.text;
            }

            var markup = "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +
              "<div class='select2-result-repository__avatar'><img src='" + ticket.owner.avatar_url + "' /></div>" +
              "<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>" +
                "<div class='select2-result-repository__title'>" + ticket.full_name + "</div>";

            if (ticket.description) {
                markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'>" + ticket.description + "</div>";
            }

            markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__statistics'>" +
              "<div class='select2-result-repository__forks'><i class='fa fa-flash'></i> " + ticket.forks_count + " Forks</div>" +
              "<div class='select2-result-repository__stargazers'><i class='fa fa-star'></i> " + ticket.stargazers_count + " Stars</div>" +
              "<div class='select2-result-repository__watchers'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> " + ticket.watchers_count + " Watchers</div>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div></div>";

            return markup;
        }

        function formatTicketSelection(ticket) {
            return ticket.Id || ticket.Subject;
        }

        $("#select-ticket-test").select2({
            placeholder: "Select a state",
            allowClear: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetAjaxAsync")",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            searchTerm: params.term,
                            pageSize: params.page,
                            pageNum: params.page
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function (data, params) {
                        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
                        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                        // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
                        // scrolling can be used
                        params.page = params.page || 1;

                        return {
                            results: data.items,
                            pagination: {
                                more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                            }
                        };
                    },
                    cache: false
                },
                escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
                minimumInputLength: 1,
                templateResult: formatTicket,
                templateSelection: formatTicketSelection
            });
    </script>
}

public async Task<ActionResult> GetAjaxAsync(string searchTerm, int pageSize, int pageNum)
{
    long number = Convert.ToInt64(searchTerm.Replace("T", null));

    var posts = await UnitOfWork.SupportPosts.Where(x => x.Number == number).ToListAsync();
    var json = new
    {
        Results = posts.Select(x => new
        {
            x.Id,
            x.NumberName
        }),
        Total = posts.Count
    };
    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

What I've noticed is, that the placeholder isn't even shown. The Select2 is initialized (as in "not a "real" dropdown anymore"), but no placeholder is shown. And when typing into the textbox, no call is even made to my controller.

There are no JavaScript errors in the console either.

Comment: try changing ``url: "@Url.Action("GetAjaxAsync")",`` to ``url: '@Url.Action("GetAjaxAsync")',``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Check console for errors

Comment: @EhsanSajjad No errors, no ajax call, no nothing...